# Use Nexus As Dependency Resolver using Gradle in Spring Boot Application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, nexus, nexus3

I am developing application using spring boot, i am using gradle as build tool, i want to configure gradle to resolve their dependencies instead of maven central or jcenter go to my Local nexus server get all dependencies from their and build project. I did't found any configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your nexus url in build.gradle.

```
repositories {
   // mavenLocal()
   // mavenCentral()
   // jcenter()
   //maven { url 'http://10.9.0.31:8099/repository/maven-public/' }
    maven { url 'http://ip:port/repository/maven-public/' }
}
```

For nexus configuration [look at this](https://blog.sonatype.com/using-nexus-3-as-your-repository-part-1-maven-artifacts)

Comment: this link is not opening.. Kindly paste full link separately. and how do i upload all jar dependencies in my nexus